# Why does VGG19 subtract the mean RGB values of inputs?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

This is found in most implementations I've seen; I don't really understand the purpose? I've heard it's a preprocessing step that helps with classification accuracy? Is it necessary, particularly for non-classification tasks, eg. generating new images, working with image activations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the most popular ways on how to normalize data is to make it have 0 mean and variance 1. It's usually done because:

1. Computational reasons - most training algorithms need your data points to have a small norm in order to run properly. It's because e.g. gradient stability, etc.
2. Dataset bias reason - if your data doesn't have a 0 mean - then it means that it constantly pushes network toward the certain direction. This must be compensated by network weights and biases what may slow down training (especially when the norm of outputs are relatively large).
3. When data is not normalized/scaled - some input coordinates (these ones with bigger means and norms) have a much greater impact on a training process. Imagine e.g. two variables - age and a binary indicator if someone had a heart attack. If you don't normalize your data - the fact that age has a higher norm than binary indicator will make this coordinate to influence training process much more than the other one. Is it plausible e.g. for predicting if someone will have another heart attack?